# How i can remove ghdl 0.29 from Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, ghdl

I follow this steps to install GHDL compiler in my Debian, but now I need to uninstall this compiler to install x64 version, and I can't.

```
By downloading the binaries and unpacking them manually:

 $ wget http://ghdl.free.fr/site/uploads/Main/ghdl-i686-linux-latest.tar

 $ sudo tar xvf ghdl-i686-linux-latest.tar
```

(This generates the file ghdl-0.29-i686-pc-linux.tar.bz2)

```
 $ cd ghdl-0.29-i686-pc-linux

 $ sudo tar -C / -jxvf ghdl-0.29-i686-pc-linux.tar.bz2
```

(This copy the files to /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib)

I have used dpkg --purge ghdl, but if I use ghdl --version, the ghdl 0.29 still in the system.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faced the same situation and this is how i did it:

goto where your tarball is and use this command

```
sudo tar -tf ghdl-0.29-i686-pc-linux.tar.bz2 | sed 's/^..//' | parallel sudo rm -rf
```

explanation:

- `tar -tf ghdl-0.29-i686-pc-linux.tar.bz2` List all files in archive.tar
- `sed 's/^..//'` Removes initial directory characters
- `parallel sudo rm -rf` removes matching files

this will leave some empty directories at `/usr/local` and if you want to get rid of them you can use

```
sudo find /usr/local/* -type d -empty -delete
```